# Devise configure_permitted_parameters not permitting :avatar variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise 4.6.1 & rails 5.2.2

I'm trying to permit `:avatar` in the `application controller` using `configure_permitted_parameters` however, when I try to update a user via the `account_update` form I get  the error:

```
Processing by RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"C3zs4PT5Ui5MCVBr6Q9S05TJi2UThwGFQ+s0kTKqb+v4JHeTrl0sfeB5p+owee3DnfJ86BkgPcfNpqgWsdPqcg==", "user"=>{"username"=>"testuser2", "email"=>"testuser2@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f4ced47a108 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20190618-18771-b0w9jf.png>, @original_filename="category-icon.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"category-icon.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Update"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Unpermitted parameter: :avatar
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Unpermitted parameter: :avatar
Unpermitted parameter: :avatar
Unpermitted parameter: :avatar
```

I tried changing

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
```

to

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters
```

However when I do that I get the error below:

undefined local variable or method `resource_class` for  `DiscussionsController:0x00007f4cee0855d8`

application_controller:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

   def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:avatar])
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this one:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update).push(:avatar)
```

And I think this is the best way indeed:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
```

Comment: Tried devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update).push(:avatar) and it returned the error "undefined method `for' for #<Devise::ParameterSanitizer:0x00007f4cf00d7480>"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not redirecting to correct controller.
Did you override the controller?
If not then it should process by 
`Devise::RegistrationsController#update as HTML`
But in your case it is processing by `RegistrationsController#update as HTML`
May be this would be the reason.